# Regex: Delete all words/strings on the lines, except html tags

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I want to delete all the lines with words, except html tags:

```
             <p class="bandy">Cars and jupiter</p>
            Comentezi folosind contul tău WordPress pentru a nu induce in eroare.
            
        </p>
                <p class="mb-40px">I love you</p>
            
    Seems to be a happy day with you next to me.
            
                </li>
<p class="simony">Select original books</p>

         bunica isi face cumparaturile la magazin.
```

**OUTPUT**

```
             <p class="bandy">Cars and jupiter</p>
            
            
        </p>
                <p class="mb-40px">I love you</p>
            
    
            
                </li>
<p class="simony">Select original books</p>
```

My regex is not too good:

FIND: `.*^(?!<p class=).*`

REPLACE BY: `LEAVE EMPTY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.*<.+?>.*$(*SKIP)(*F)|.`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           # begining of line
    .*          # 0 or more any character
    <.+?>       # any tag
    .*          # 0 or more any character
$           # end of line
    (*SKIP)     # skip this match
    (*F)        # and declare a failure
  |           # OR
    .           # any character
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: your regex must be updates, because in the case below, will delete the line with words that ends with `</p>` For example: `I go to a shop</p>`  Check here:

https://regex101.com/r/wCNfNg/1

Comment: @HellenaCrainicu: Good catch, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^((?!<p class=.+</p>).)*$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**OR**

- Find what: `^((?!<p class=).)*$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`

Comment: You should test before posting. This doesn't produce the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^[^</>\r\n]+$`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>